# Reading a PPM file in C++ (only P6 format without comments) and save as image

Tags: c++, ppm

I have an exercise where I need to read a PPM file and save its content as an image in C++. Then I want to calculate the average brightness. I have 3 header file. I managed to read the file and check the P6 value, width, height and depth. How can i extract the image data from the file in order to make the image object in order to calculate the average brightness?

Color.h

```
namespace imaging 
{
    /*! An alias for the floating point representation of color components (32bit per color channel).
     */
    typedef float component_t;


    class Color 
    {
    public: 
        // members
        component_t r, 
                    g, 
                    b; 

        // member functions


        component_t & operator [] (size_t index)
        {
            return *(&r + index);
        }


        Color operator + (Color & right)
        {
            Color left;
            left.r = r + right.r;
            left.g = g + right.g;
            left.b = b + right.b;
            return left;
        }

        // constructors


        Color(component_t r, component_t g, component_t b) : r(r), g(g), b(b) {}

        Color() : r(0), g(0), b(0) {}
    };
```

Image.h

```
namespace imaging {
class Image
    {
    public:
        enum channel_t {RED=0,GREEN, BLUE};                                                          
    protected:
        component_t * buffer;                        

        unsigned int width,                          
                     height;                         

    public:
        // metric accessors


        const unsigned int getWidth() const {return width;}      


        const unsigned int getHeight() const {return height;}   

        // data accessors


        component_t * getRawDataPtr();                           


        Color getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const;

        // data mutators


        void setPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Color & value); 


        void setData(const component_t * & data_ptr);            


        void resize(unsigned int new_width, unsigned int new_height);

        // constructors and destructor

        /*! Default constructor.

         */
        Image();                                                    

        /*! Constructor with width and height specification.
         * 


         */
        Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height);

        // Constructor with data initialization

        Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const component_t * data_ptr);

        /*! Copy constructor.

         */
        Image(const Image &src);

        /*! The Image destructor.

         */
        ~Image();

        /*! Copy assignment operator.*/

        Image & operator = (const Image & right);

    };
}
```

ppm_format.h

```
namespace imaging
{
    /*! Reads a PPM image file and returns a pointer to a newly allocated Image object containing the image. 
     */
    Image * ReadPPM(const char * filename);


} //namespace imaging
```

I wrote this code for the reading PPM file method:

```
Image * ReadPPM(const char* filename) {
ifstream ifs;
            string v1; //for the P6 value
            int v2,v3,v4; //for width, height and color depth
            cin.getline(filename, 20);

            ifs.open(filename,ios::binary);  
            if (ifs.is_open()) {

                    while (ifs.good()){
                        if (ifs>>v1>>v2>>v3>>v4){
                        int height = v2;
                        int width = v3;
                        if (v1!="P6") {
                            cout<<"Unsupported type of ppm file(not P6)"<<endl;
                            ifs.close();
                            exit(0);
                        }

                        if (v2<1){
                            cout<<"Unsupported width"<<endl;
                            ifs.close();
                            exit(0);
                        }
                        if (v3<1){
                            cout<<"Unsupported height"<<endl;
                            ifs.close();
                            exit(0);
                        }

                        if (v4<1 || v4>255){
                            cout<<"Unsupported number of bits"<<endl;
                            ifs.close();
                            exit(0);
                        }

                        //cout<<v1<<endl<<height<<endl<<width;

                        } 

                    }
            }


            else if (!ifs.is_open()) {
                    cout<<"The file with name: "<<filename<<" does not exist";
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            ifs.close(); 
            // end of reading the file

             //start making the image

            Image image = new Image(v2,v3);
            return image;

}
```

I wrote this code for reading and saving the image data. The problem is that i want to extract the image data as component_t type (float).
`char* data = new char[3*height*width];
                        int bytesPerLn = width*3;
                        for (int i=0;i<height;i++){
                            char* tmp = new char[bytesPerLn];
                            ifs.getline(tmp,bytesPerLn);
                            cout<<tmp;
                            strcat(data,tmp);
                        }
                        cout<<data;`

Comment: The P6 format is a *binary* file format, you can't read it as a text file using text input like `>>`.

Comment: As for the image data, it follows the "header", and is 24 bits per pixel (8 bits (one byte) for each of the colors). So to read it you need to read three bytes at a time to get one pixel.

Comment: So how can i read three bytes at a time for each pixel? The image data size is 3*width*height?

Comment: Please read about the [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) function.